# Helping with jetpack compose checkbox

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Need help with following codes where Checkbox is not working. I am using the checkbox to round up billWithTip value. Otherwise, billWithTip works fine, displaying the right double value. However, as I check mark the check box, the billWithTip displays 0.0. Unable to figure out the reason. Would appreciate if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance

```
@Composable
fun CalculateTipLayout() {
    var billAmount by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var tipPercent by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var checkBoxStatus by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var billWithTip by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    billWithTip = calculateTip(
        amount = billAmount.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0,
        tip = tipPercent.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
    )
   if (checkBoxStatus) {
      billWithTip =  kotlin.math.ceil(billWithTip.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0).toString()
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .statusBarsPadding()
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .safeDrawingPadding(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "This is your Bill:",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp, top = 0.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.Start),
            fontSize = 30.sp, textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline,
        )
        BillAmount(
            billAmount = billAmount, BillAmountChange = { newAmount -> billAmount = newAmount },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        )
        TipPercent(
            tipPercent = tipPercent, tipPercentChange = { newTip -> tipPercent = newTip },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        )
        Row(modifier = Modifier) {
            Text(
                text = "Round the tip?", fontSize = 30.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            Checkbox(
                checked = checkBoxStatus,
                onCheckedChange = { newCheckBoxStatus: Boolean ->
                    checkBoxStatus = newCheckBoxStatus
                },
                enabled = true,
            )
        }
        if (checkBoxStatus) {
            billWithTip =  kotlin.math.ceil(billWithTip.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0).toString()
        }

        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.total_bill_amount, billWithTip),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.Start),
            fontSize = 25.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Companion.Bold,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try updating `billWithTip`  value in `onCheckChange` listener?

Comment: Also, can you share `calculateTip` function? It maybe `0.0` because of invalid calculation or `billAmount` and `tipAmount` is null!

Comment: Hi Megh, below it is: `fun calculateTip(amount: Double, tip: Double): String {
    val tipCalculated = (amount * (tip / 100))
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount + tipCalculated)
}`

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. When I am calculating the `billWithTip` value using this:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount + tipCalculated)
```

the `$` symbol is generating NaN. I modified the `if` statement with the following:

```
if (checkBoxStatus) {
    billWithTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
                  .format(kotlin.math.ceil(billWithTip.split("$").last().toDouble()))
}
```

Now round up is working fine.